# How do I get the RecordTypeId for a Person Account using Describe method?

Tags: record-type, describesobject, person-accounts

I can get them by running the following query

```
SELECT Name, SobjectType, IsPersonType 
FROM RecordType 
WHERE SobjectType='Account' AND IsPersonType=True
```

or by doing

```
    public Id personRECORDTYPEID = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('PersonType').getRecordTypeId();
```

but I can't seem to get it right using my code below. I can't use the above because my code is reading any kind of object so specifing 'Account' is not really an option. I want to keep it generic for any type of object or recordtype by passing them in.

I pass the object name and recordtype name to this code, but it doesn't work for a PersonAccount.

```
    public static Id getRecordTypeIdForObject(String objName, String recTypeName) {
    return ((SObject)Type.forName(objName).newInstance())
        .getSObjectType()
        .getDescribe()
        .getRecordTypeInfosByName()
        .get(recTypeName)
        .getRecordTypeId();
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to run `getRecordTypeIdForObject('PersonAccount', 'PersonType')`? That won't work, because `PersonAccount` is not an Sobject type. I would expect  `getRecordTypeIdForObject('Account', 'PersonType')` to work - if you're using that and it's not working, please specify what error or other result you're getting.

Comment: I use 'Account' and 'PersonType', but it returns null

Comment: If `PersonType` is really the correct Recordtype Name, then it should work. If it's not, then your second example would fail Recordtype Names often have spaces in them, though. Can you paste the results of your first query?

Comment: One of the record types does have a space in it yes. I didn't think that would matter?

Comment: I mean, the string you pass has to match the Map key. `getRecordTypeInfosByName()` gets a Map whose key is the recordtype labels, which may have spaces. `'Person Type'` and `'PersonType'` are two different strings/map keys. Maybe [getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeSObjectResult_getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName) is better for your use case (though DeveloperName isn't necessarily just removing the spaces).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is going on for you, but in my developer Person Accounts org I tried:

```
System.debug(
  ((SObject)Type.forName('Account').newInstance())
  .getSObjectType()
  .getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName()
);
```

Here's what I got:

```
19:23:51.2 (40515202)|USER_DEBUG|[1]|DEBUG|{
Business Account=Schema.RecordTypeInfo[getDeveloperName=Business_Account;getName=Business Account;getRecordTypeId=01246000000QTvKAAW;isActive=true;isAvailable=true;isDefaultRecordTypeMapping=false;isMaster=false;], 
Master=Schema.RecordTypeInfo[getDeveloperName=Master;getName=Master;getRecordTypeId=012000000000000AAA;isActive=true;isAvailable=true;isDefaultRecordTypeMapping=false;isMaster=true;],
Person Account=Schema.RecordTypeInfo[getDeveloperName=PersonAccount;getName=Person Account;getRecordTypeId=01246000000QUHTAA4;isActive=true;isAvailable=true;isDefaultRecordTypeMapping=true;isMaster=false;]}
```

So in principle this should work fine. What kind of errors are you getting?